# App registry isn't ready yet while working with django rest framework.Tried everything

Tags: django

I am newbie to django and I am trying to work with serializers in django-rest-framework module.But each time I am shooted with the following error message

**App registry isn't ready yet**strong text****

I am following all the required steps but still being caught by this error.what can be the reason kindly help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to go through documentation first. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#standalone-scripts